# Tab panel table header not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a script which contains two tab panels both of which display a table header. The table are populated using an Ajax call and the response is formatted and displays the data. When I run the code the first tab panel display the table header displays perfectly with all the table columns spaced out using percentages.

When I click on the second tab panel header table header are all bunched up to the left. BUT, if I manually resize the browser windows the header in the second tab panel auto adjusts to the correct layout, and the first tab panel header is bunched to the left. I can see in the inspect console the header widths suddenly appear.

I think is maybe a styling issue which is why I have tagged is CSS, but I may be wrong.

The tab panels:

First tab panel

```
<div class="TabbedPanelsContentGroup">
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
    <table name="timeline" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="userTableInbound" style="width:100%" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Flight No</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Schedule Time</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Code</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Name</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">IO</div></th>
      <th width="6%"><div class="LogoSize"></div></th>
      <th width="32%"><div class="TableHeaderText"></div></th>
      <th width="2%"><div class="TableHeaderTextNormal">Action</div></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Second tab panel

```
  <div class="TabbedPanelsContent">
    <table name="timeline" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  id="userTableOutbound" style="width:100%" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Flight No</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Schedule Time</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Code</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Name</div></th>
      <th width="12%"><div class="TableHeaderText">IO</div></th>
      <th width="6%"><div class="LogoSize"></div></th>
      <th width="32%"><div class="TableHeaderText"></div></th>
      <th width="2%"><div class="TableHeaderTextNormal">Action</div></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The code that makes the Ajax call and formats the response:

```
var depart;
var airlinelogopath = "<?php echo $AirlineImagePath;?>";
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#userTableOutbound').DataTable( {
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    bInfo : false,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scrollY: "400px",
    responsive: true,
    language: {
      emptyTable: "Please wait .. biulding timeline",
      loadingRecords: "No data available in table ",
      zeroRecords: "No matching records found"
    },
    "stripeClasses": [ 'odd-row', 'even-row' ]
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'flight-outbound.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response){
      var len = response.length;
      $("#userTableOutbound tbody").html("");
      for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        var recordid = response[i].RecordID;
        var flightno = response[i].FlightNo;
        var airlinecode = response[i].AirlineCode;
        var airlinename = response[i].AirlineName;
        var airlinelogo = response[i].AirlineLogo;
        var schedtime = response[i].ScheduleTime;
        var io = response[i].IO;
        if( io == "I") {
          depart = "In bound";
        } else {
          depart = "Out bound";
        }
        var d = new Date();
    var tr_str = "<tr class='TableText'>" +
        "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;width:12%;'>" + flightno + " </td>" +
        "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;width:12%;'>" + schedtime + "</td>" +
        "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;width:12%;'>" + airlinecode + " </td>" +
        "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;width:12%;'>" + airlinename + "</td>" +
        "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;width:12%;'>" + depart + "</td>" +
        "<td style='color:#333;width:9px;height:9px;width:6%;'><input name='view' type='image' src='" + airlinelogopath + ""  + airlinelogo + "' id=" + recordid + " class='btn  btn-xs btn-block single-preview'></td>" +
        "<td style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;width:32%;'></td>" +
        "<td align='center'  style='color:#333;font-size:0.7em;width:2%;'><input type='button' name='edit' value='View' id=" + recordid + " class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block view_data_carousel'></td>" +
        "</tr>";
        $("#userTableOutbound tbody").append(tr_str);
      }
     }
  });
});
```

When I inspect the code in the console I see the following which display the style width as 0px even them the width of the th is set.
If I remove the th width, is is still the same showing the style width as 0px.

```
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Flight No</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Schedule Time</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Code</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Name</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">IO</div></th>
<th width="6%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="LogoSize"></div></th>
<th width="32%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="TableHeaderText"></div></th>
<th width="2%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;"><div class="TableHeaderTextNormal">Action</div></th>
```

After a browser window resize:

```
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 204px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Flight No</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 206px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Schedule Time</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 206px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Code</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 207px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">Airline Name</div></th>
<th width="12%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 206px;"><div class="TableHeaderText">IO</div></th>
<th width="6%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 102px;"><div class="LogoSize"></div></th>
<th width="32%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 552px;"><div class="TableHeaderText"></div></th>
<th width="2%" class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 46px;"><div class="TableHeaderTextNormal">Action</div></th>
```

The data for the second tab panel display correctly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you try  to reload the table after appending all table rows ? In your case $('#userTableOutbound').DataTable().ajax.reload();

Comment: @angel.bonev hi and thanks for looking at this. I am not sure why I would need to reload the table, remember I am not appending any more rows just changing tabs.

Comment: my mistake, you need to redraw it , I think in you case when the second tab is hidden the width is 0, so when DataTable is drawing the second table it gets zero width from the second tab container, So you can try this in console `$('#userTableOutbound').DataTable().columns.adjust().draw();` , after you open the second tab. It's just a guess